# Strategy to save the unsaved data in data control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a repeater control and some controls like dropdown/Buttons/Checklist for search as all these controls do postback. I have some data entry controls in each row of Repeater. The business rule is if you leave the repeater row or repeater control and click the search control before performing the search you need to save the unsaved data in the repeater control.

My query is What strategy to adopt for saving the repeater control data in case you have some unsaved data and you are clicking at the search control.

This should also be valid in case you are changing the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

introduce a flag say "isdirty" in ur code. Isdirty will be set if any changes are made respective to the controls added in the grid. so if ur page is dirty then u can prompt for saving using javascript or anyother technique u found suitable.